# gunzip django request as stream

Tags: python, django

I'm needing to gunzip the body of a POST request. I've got something basic working:

```
    def read_input(request):
        if "HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING" in request.META:
            if request.META["HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING"] == "gzip":
                data = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(request.read()))
```

However the input is potentially very large and materializing the content using StringIO will result in running out of memory. How can I do this without materializing the content?
Note: I need to generate a file-like object.

Comment: not sure how to get django to stream, but you can use `zlib` to do the streaming processing when you do.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work because I need a file-like object as the result and couldn't work out how to do that.